# get environment variable from file or EV with awk to use it as EV

Tags: shell, if-statement, awk, scripting

excuse me but I am a beginner and can't imagine how to solve my puzzle in Linux shell scripting.

I have the file. File with name /etc/hostname or environment variable $HOSTNAME
in my case in this file is wroten RxPower-1 or TiPower-1

How I can get the first part **RxPower** or **TiPower** to use it later as an environment variable. I try to use awk but without success. Sorry for my bad English but this is not my mother language.

awk -F"-" '{if ($1=="RxPower") mm=$1;else mm=TiPower}' /etc/hostname

thank you Advance for your help !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `sed` to export the variable

```
$ export var1=$(sed  's/\([^-]*\).*/\1/' /etc/hostname)
```

or using `awk`

```
$ export var1=$(awk -F"-" '{print $1}' /etc/hostname)
```